# Tensorflow and Tensorflow.JS giving different predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have trained a model in Tensorflow and converting the model to Tensorflow.js. My model is based on mobilenet v2 with some of the final layers removed and replaced with deconvolution layers.

After conversion, my model is predicting different from the Python TF model even with the same data.

I have noticed the following warnings in the conversion process:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization/FusedBatchNormV3'
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3'
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization_2/FusedBatchNormV3'
```

The full conversion log is:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format tf_saved_model \
                       ../models/keras_saved_model/pose_mobilenet_v2_075/1/ \
                       ../models/tfjs/pose_mobilenet_v2_075/1

2020-08-22 16:23:06.107303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-08-22 16:23:08.772664: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-08-22 16:23:08.772794: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-08-22 16:23:08.772929: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (c316cecfe6ff): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-08-22 16:23:08.773528: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-22 16:23:08.795662: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2304000000 Hz
2020-08-22 16:23:08.796681: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x556c9c823e90 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-22 16:23:08.796749: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-22 16:23:18.570250: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:69] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
2020-08-22 16:23:18.571471: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-08-22 16:23:18.650737: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-08-22 16:23:18.650819: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: Graph size after: 1062 nodes (787), 1040 edges (765), time = 33.855ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:18.650841: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.605ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298407: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298481: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   debug_stripper: debug_stripper did nothing. time = 0.831ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298502: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   model_pruner: Graph size after: 468 nodes (-548), 480 edges (-548), time = 5.86ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298519: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 32.234ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298533: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 27.212ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298565: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 5.536ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298604: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   model_pruner: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 3.384ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298621: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 14.581ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298641: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 37.403ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298656: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 6.571ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298672: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   debug_stripper: debug_stripper did nothing. time = 0.547ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298713: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   model_pruner: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 2.079ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298733: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 23.091ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298794: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 23.129ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298812: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 4.498ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298825: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   model_pruner: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 2.181ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298833: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 22.593ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298845: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 21.459ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:20.298853: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 468 nodes (0), 480 edges (0), time = 4.195ms.
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization/FusedBatchNormV3'
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3'
WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D or DepthwiseConv2dNative input to 'StatefulPartitionedCall/bremont_mobilenetv2_0.75/batch_normalization_2/FusedBatchNormV3'
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023423: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:816] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023493: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   remapper: Graph size after: 488 nodes (-31), 299 edges (-28), time = 18.115ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023513: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 260 nodes (-228), 272 edges (-27), time = 25.169ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023532: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 6.566ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023552: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 2.274ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023591: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   remapper: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 1.215ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023668: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 6.636ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023740: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   arithmetic_optimizer: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 6.141ms.
2020-08-22 16:23:25.023838: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:818]   dependency_optimizer: Graph size after: 260 nodes (0), 272 edges (0), time = 2.42ms.
Writing weight file ../models/tfjs/pose_mobilenet_v2_075/1/model.json...
```

To give an example of output, this is from Python:

```
output[0,0,0]
    
array([ 0.00079024, -0.0020999 ,  0.00075853, -0.00058321,  0.00695629,
            0.00209076,  0.00031798, -0.00092323, -0.00198799, -0.0020462 ,
            0.00417227], dtype=float32)
```

and from tensorflow.js for the same input data:

```
r.arraySync()[0][0][0]

[
  0.0010096959304064512,
  -0.0024646464735269547,
  0.0010527926497161388,
  0.0008166381157934666,
  0.005697209388017654,
  0.0010445881634950638,
  0.0010996845085173845,
  -0.0013098083436489105,
  -0.0022477181628346443,
  -0.002731590997427702,
  0.003211272181943059
]
```

I've copied the relevant model creation and conversion code to this repo https://github.com/markstrefford/tf-to-tfjs

From looking around, most of the instances of this problem seem to be due to earlier version of tf.js, but I am running recent version of Tensorflow (2.3), Tensorflow JS converter (2.3) and Tensorflow.js (2.0.1). I've also tried tf-node.js (version 2.3) but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK so in discussions with the tf.js guys, these differences in output are expected and the warnings don't seem to have caused any issues with my model accuracy.